# Using zip/tar from gradle distribution plugin

Tags: java, gradle, compilation, installation

I need to know the best way to actually use the outputs from Gradle's distribution/ application plugin. I am trying to package my Java project in a way that can be easily installed and used (i.e, put in a `PATH` location, etc).

I know I can package the project just fine in a tar/zip, but this isn't exactly something I can just put in a `PATH` location and just run it like a normal program (I've tried, even symmlinking to the executable in the unzipped folder, I ran into issues with not being able to find the libs).

How can I package my Java project with gradle so that it can be installed easily on a machine? I have searched through docs for a while but come up empty. It is possible that I am missing something, but all I can see how to do is to make a tar/zip which works as a program, but is not easily installed/ used outside of the bin folder of the unzipped zip.

Bonus points for ways to have gradle automatically make installers (.deb, .rpm, windows installer)

Comment: The out put of gradle will be jar file, it it is required, it can be executable jar.What is the meaning of easily installed? Provide more specific details with code so that people can help you.

Comment: @Sambit this is true of the lib but not the distro. So if you are trying to run with the deps unbundled you would need to use the tar.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [*application plugin*](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) which extends the *distribution plugin* adding the executable bundling features you seek. From the documentation:

> The Application plugin facilitates creating an executable JVM application. It makes it easy to start the application locally during development, and to package the application as a TAR and/or ZIP including operating system specific start scripts.

This plugin adds the tasks [`installDist`, `distZip`, `distTar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks), to install a java application distribution, package it as a zip and package it as a tar respectively, with standard scripts for the specific OS. To customize these OS specific scripts generated for the bundle (to start up the application) configure a [**`CreateStartScripts`**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html) task.

Comment: I am actually using the application plugin, I know I can get those zip/tars. My question is how to use them like any other executable (pop it into a bin, is callable).

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I ended up using https://github.com/i-net-software/SetupBuilder

I found it a little confusing at first, but I use it to create installers such as .deb, and can use my java application like any other program.